# React native advantage? how to create both web and app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to create web and android application using react. can I use both reactJs and react native. If I create web app by using reactJs, how to convert web into android application (reactjs into react native).
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally in my projects have not seen a way of doing this automatically. There are some things that you might wish to look at however.

- https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web - Seems to allow you to use the same components from react native directly in a react project. So the idea being you write your react native project and then import this package for the web build and voila.

I have ended up manually managing the proccess. If you layout your application keeping your application logic completely seperate from any display component logic the process really isn't that painful. Not sure if there is a better guide but this might give you an idea http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/

You could also use something like webpack to automate this process of swapping components / packages out for native / web.